# where to set Content-Security-Policy to allow embeding Ui or Api?

Tags: angular

I am getting a error when trying to embed a website A's UI in Website B's UI

> Refused to frame 'https://A-UI.somewhere.any/' because an ancestor
> violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
> "frame-ancestors 'self' X-Frame-Options: DENY".

Content-Security-Policy are set in A's UI or Api?

Comment: They are usually set as a header in the website.